# django-orm case-insensitive order by

Tags: django, case-insensitive, fetch, django-orm

I know, I can run a case insensitive search from DJango ORM. Like,

```
User.objects.filter(first_name__contains="jake")
User.objects.filter(first_name__contains="sulley")
User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains="Jake")
User.objects.filter(first_name__icontains="Sulley")
```

And also, I can fetch them as

```
user_list = User.objects.all().order_by("first_name")
# sequence: (Jake, Sulley, jake, sulley)
user_list = User.objects.all().order_by("-first_name") # for reverse
# sequence: (sulley, jake, Sulley, Jake)
```

Is there a direct way for a case-insensitive fetch?? As in I want a sequence as

```
# desired sequence: jake, Jake, sulley, Sulley
```

If not, then suggest a best way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is for postgresql, but maybe it will be useful for other databases too: http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2007/11/20/case-insensitive-ordering-with-django-and-postgresql/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This answer is outdated, follow [top voted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506461/568270) with django >= 1.8**

I found solution using .extra

```
class MyModelName(models.Model):
   is_mine = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


MyModelName.objects.filter( is_mine=1 ).extra(\
    select={'lower_name':'lower(name)'}).order_by('lower_name')
```

original link:

http://naorrosenberg.blogspot.fi/2011/04/django-models-orderby-charfield-case.html

Comment: This won't work when traversing relationship, i.e "name__something" , however you can make it works with the Lower function since django 1.8 : 'from django.db.models.functions import Lower' and 'MyModelName.objects.order_by(Lower('name_something'))' here it is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/db/models/functions/#Lower

Answer (score 121):

Since Django 1.8 it is possible with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
MyModel.objects.order_by(Lower('myfield'))
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6498

Comment: Is it possible to use Lower with multiple columns? I can only seem to get it to work with one column.

Comment: It is possible: User.objects.order_by(Lower('username'), Lower('email'))

Comment: models.py class Meta: ordering = [Lower('name')]

Comment: for descending order use:

MyModel.objects.order_by(Lower('myfield').desc())

Answer (score 2):

Lets take an example where you have to do a case insensitive order by of the field **"first_name"** from the **User** Model

```py
# Importing the Lower Function
from django.db.models.functions import Lower


#For ordering by Ascending order
User.objects.all().order_by(Lower('first_name'))

#For ordering by Descending order
User.objects.all().order_by(Lower('first_name').desc())
```

The **Lower** function converts all the **"first_name"** values into lowercase, and then it's ordered accordingly.