# Case insensitive queryset sorting in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-queryset

Is it possible to sort Django queryset case insensitively? This query:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('title')
```

uses case sensitive sorting. The result is sorted like this:

```
X..
a..
b..
```

But I would like to sort titles like this:

```
a..
b..
X..
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it with the ORM directly. But using the [`extra()` clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra), you can try doing this:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'case_insensitive_title': 'lower(title)'}).order_by('case_insensitive_title')
```

Comment: Check answer on [django-orm case-insensitive order by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506461/1538221). Since version 1.8 you can use `Lower` function on `order_by()` method.