# how to get objects in case insensitive order using model manager method in django

Tags: django, django-models

i want to display objects in case insensitive order

for eg

```
class Organization(models.model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    administrator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True,related_name = 'OrgAdmin')
    types = models.ManyToManyField(OrganizationType,blank=True, null=True)
```

to display objects ordered by name

```
Organization.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

will display in case sensitive

soo what will be option for case insensitive order

how we can achieve this using model method

Comment: possible duplicate of [django-orm case-insensitive order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use extra:

```
Organization.objects.extra(select={'lower_name':'lower(name)'}).order_by('lower_name')
```

[django-orm case-insensitive order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by)

Edit:

Please check that

```
Organization.objects.extra(select={'lower_name':'lower(administrator__name)'}).order_by('lower_name')
```

Comment: i tried above with foreign key field

Organization.objects.filter().extra(select={'lower_administrator':'lower(administrator)'}‌​).order_by('lower_administrator')

gives error 
OperationalError: no such column: administrator

Answer (score 0):

There's a clear distinction what you should do in model and what in model manager. Basically, models should only contain methods that deal with *single instance*, while custom model managers should be used to contain any logic that operates on model *lists* or do custom queries.

So, in your example this should look like:

```
class OrganizationManager(models.Manager):
    def insensitive(self):
        return self.all().extra(select={'name_lower': 'lower(name)'}, order_by=['name_lower'])

class Organization(models.model):
    objects = OrganizationManager()
```

And you can use it like

```
orgs_insensitive = Organization.objects.insensitive()
```

Refer to django [model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) docs for details.

*EDIT*: turns out django does not support `filter` field lookups for order, so according to the last comment on [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6498), case insensitive ordering should be done like

```
my_model.objects.all().extra(select={'imf': 'UPPER(my_field)'}, order_by=['imf'])
```

Comment: Could downvoter please explain where exactly am I wrong?

Comment: Hey @JOHN thnx, 
but i tried this, exposing error like 
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'name_iexact' into field. Choices are:id, name, phone ... etc :(

Comment: This is your typo, not mine :)

Comment: what will be query in case of foreign key field  ...
Organization.objects.all().extra(select={'imf': 'UPPER(administrator)'}, order_by=['imf'])
administrator is foreign key here ....

OperationalError: no such column: administrator

Comment: That could help if you post complete problem the first time. What would be next, `administrator` is calculated field based on user-defined procedure? Aside of that, have you considered using raw sql queries?

Comment: actually , m trying the same ... ( with raw )

Answer (score 0):

it possible to get case insensitive objects based on foreign key attribute (like administrator mentioned above) using raw query.

```
Organization.objects.raw('select * from organization o,auth_user a on o.administrator_id=a.id order by a.username COLLATE NOCASE ASC')
```