# Is it possible to do case-insensitive ordering in descending order with the Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

Django has the `Lower` function, but this only works with `ASC` (ascending) ordered queries.

**Example URL:**

```
'/api/locations/?ordering=-number,name'
```

We were using the below pattern:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

class OrderingQuerySetMixin(object):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        ordering = self.request.query_params.get('ordering', None)
        if ordering:
            if ordering.startswith('-'):
                queryset = queryset.order_by(Lower(ordering[1:])).reverse()
            else:
                queryset = queryset.order_by(Lower(ordering))
        return queryset
```

The problem with this pattern is it doesn't work for ordering multiple fields.  The only way to do this would be to pass the `descending` argument directly to `Lower`, and lower fails with anything like `'-myfield'` like the normal Django ORM does for descending ordering.

Here's the current pattern, which accepts multiple arguments for ordering, but does not handle descending:

```
class OrderingQuerySetMixin(object):
    """Return a case-insensitive ordered queryset."""

    def eval_param(self, param):
        if param.startswith('-'):
            return param[1:]
        else:
            return param

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        ordering = self.request.query_params.get('ordering', None)
        if ordering:
            queryset = queryset.order_by(
                *[Lower(self.eval_param(p)) for p in ordering.split(',')]
            )
        return queryset
```

Comment: Use `.extra()`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by

Comment: @ShangWang that worked.  Thanks!

Comment: what is the final code. i am also looking for a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344450/django-drf-how-to-do-case-insensitive-ordering

Answer (score 2):

```py
#Import Lower function
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

#For Ascending order
queryset.order_by(Lower('field_name'))

#For Descending order
queryset.order_by(Lower('field_name').desc())
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information