# Django (DRF): How to do case-insensitive ordering

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an api with ?ordering=name,type

I want both the name and the type to be as case-insensitive

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got the solution from `https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3280`

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter


class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)

        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if field.startswith('-'):
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field).asc())
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)

        return queryset
```

then use it in the ListView

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter,CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter]
    search_fields = ['name','slug']
```

Comment: In postgres having issue with annotated count field.         function lower(bigint) does not exist

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to directly order with `Lower` db model function

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
# ...
    
class UsersViewSet(models.Model):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by(Lower('username'))
```