# Django order by

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django, I am trying to order my objects by field `last_name` but I think I might be missing something, this is how my function looks:

```
def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().list(*args, **kwargs)
        data = data.data
        x = self.queryset.order_by('last_name')
        print(x)  # I'm priting X but I still get list not ordered by last_name 
        return Response(data)
```

## UPdate

I think what I must do is affect the variable ordering in my Model meta class but I need it to order by lowercase:

```
class Meta(DRYPermissionModel.Meta):

    ordering = ['username'] # ORDER BY user_name but as if the string was lower case
```

Comment: you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by) link if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong here is in `self.queryset`. You need to make sure that this variable has similar to `model.objects.all()`. Only then will your order by work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on `ORDER BY user_name but as if the string was lower case`

Comment: the thing is that username can be: Alex.Alexandros or alex.alexandros. I want for it to order as if it was lower case

Comment: So in case of Alex.Alexandros or alex.alexandros, you want the order to be the same i.e. you want your ordering to be case-insensitive. Is that correct?

Comment: Try using `ordering = [lower('username')]`

Comment: Perhaps we need to take a step back. Meta class only give so much functionality. Lets look at `self.queryset.order_by('last_name')`. Does that give you some result? If it does, could I get a sample?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually what solved my issue:

```
def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ It returns the list of users ordered by user_name case insentive """
        users = self.queryset.order_by(Lower('username'))
        serializer = serializers.UserSerializer
        return Response(serializer(users, many=True).data)
```