# Django Model: Meta: how to have default ordering case-insensitive

Tags: django, django-models

I am having a Django Model as shown below: I know that we can set the default ordering in the Meta class.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
```

As the ordering is set to name here. What i found is, it is ordering by case-sensitive. So how to make it case-insensitive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-orm case-insensitive order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by)

Comment: Its not duplicate. Here we are talking about the meta class. To know how to achieve that in Meta class. Or whether its possible or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible set the default order to case-insensitive in the model meta options ([source](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6498)).

What you can do is use the [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method of the `QuerySet` of your model:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

Ingredient.objects.order_by(Lower('name'))
```

As stated already in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34506461/6935780)

To be able to have it as a default ordering (and avoid repeating the `order_by` method on each one of your querysets), you might want to create a [custom `Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset) class for your `Ingredient` model:

```
# managers.py
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

class OrderedIngredientManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by(Lower('name'))

# models.py
from .managers import OrderedIngredientManager

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    ordered_objects = OrderedIngredientManager()
```

So you can have all your `QuerySet` ordered:

```
Ingredient.ordered_objects.all()
```

Comment: Better even if this non-standard behaviour is placed in a custom Manager method order_by_ci().

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer to also explain how to add a custom `Manager` class with the default ordering.

Answer (score 13):

I tested with django 2.0.7 and using Upper works :

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Upper

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = [Upper('name'), ]

name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,null=False)
```

Comment: from django.db.models.functions import Upper

Comment: Yep, confirmed this works in Django 2.2.  You can use either `Upper` or `Lower`.

Comment: Just an edit, I actually got errors in the Admin after making this change. Not entirely sure why, but had to remove it.

Comment: Tested with Django==2.2.3, vanilla admin works fine.

Comment: It is/was a bug actually, see:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30557

Don't think that's made it to the 2.2 stable release yet but it's in the Django 3.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by using F from django models

```
from django.db.models import F
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = [F('name').asc(nulls_last=True)]
```