# django-orm case-insensitive group by

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm trying to annotate my data with their count in a case-insensitive manner. I found this similar question: [django-orm case-insensitive order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by) and tried this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower
Posts.objects.filter(published=True).values('author').annotate(Lower('author'))
```

However it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'Lower' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I also tried this one:

```
Posts.objects.filter(published=True).values('author').annotate(c=Count(Lower('author')))
```

It has no effect and the result is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try annotating you data using `Lower` before `Count`:

```py
Posts.objects.filter(published=True).annotate(lauthor=Lower('author')).values('lauthor').annotate(c=Count('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is your Post model, but I recommend using `order_by`

```py
Posts.objects.filter(published=True).annotate(lauthor=Lower('author')).values('lauthor').annotate(c=Count('lauthor')).order_by('lauthor')
```