# How to sort a queryset based on objects' foreign key by sorted method?

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-models, django-queryset

I'm happy with the instruction to do sorting:

```
sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj.name.lower(), reverse=True)
```

But as I need to sort the queryset by obj's foreign key's field. It looks invalid with: (Sort won't work! The order didn't change.)

```
sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj.fkname.name.lower(), reverse=True)
```

which fkname is the foreign key of the object.
I don't want to do sorting like this:

```
Course.objects.order_by("subject__name")[0].name  # The course cls has a FK to Subject.
```

Can this be possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django-orm case-insensitive order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409047/django-orm-case-insensitive-order-by)

Comment: @ThomWiggers NO, I don't want to use Django's orm order_by query. I want to tuse sorted() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can also sort a queryset based on objects' foreign key using the `sorted()` function in Python, try the following example:

```py
qs = Course.objects.select_related("subject").all()
sorted_qs = sorted(qs, key=lambda obj: obj.subject.name.lower(), reverse=True)
```

In this example, `qs` is a queryset of `Course` objects that you want to sort by the `name` field of the related `Subject` object.

The `reverse` parameter in the `sorted()` function specifies the sorting order. If it's `True`, the queryset will be sorted in descending order.

Comment: But the sorting result remains old.

Comment: @Alston If the sorting result is still old, it's possible that the `Course` objects in your queryset don't have a related `Subject` object, try to use `select_related()`, see edited answer.

Comment: It works! I forgot sorted() will return a new qs instead of just sorting the original one. THANKS! I'm so stupid... You don't have to add select_related!  It's all because I forgot to catch the new return qs.